# How get Aray value

Tags: magento2

```
 Array
 (
[0] => Array
    (
        [value] => 0
        [label] => NOT LOGGED IN
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [value] => 1
        [label] => General
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [value] => 2
        [label] => Wholesale
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [value] => 3
        [label] => Retailer
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [value] => 4
        [label] => Basic Purchase
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [value] => 5
        [label] => Purchase Group
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [value] => 6
        [label] => Payment Failed Group
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [value] => 7
        [label] => Cancel Group
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [value] => 8
        [label] => Partner Pricing
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [value] => 9
        [label] => Expert User Group
    )

 )
```

i am getting this array now i want all lable value just label values in array and want us in array.

Answer (score 0):

Please check http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-column.php

This should work:

```
$labels = array_column($array, 'label');
print_r($labels);
```

For Magento collection you can use ...

```
$collection->getColumnValues('label')
```

Answer (score 0):

getting payment method labels

```
foreach ($array as $value) 
{
 $all_labels=$value['label'];
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer to assist learners.Code only answers are not always helpful. Use the [edit] button to add more text.

Answer (score 0):

```
$labelarray = array();
foreach ($valuearray as $value) 
{
   $labelarray[] = $value['label'];
}
print_r($labelarray);
```

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer to help learners. Code only answers are not always helpful.